# Outputting an object (pointer) in a map to a binary file

Tags: c++, class, object, dictionary, iterator

I have a map with pointers to objects of a class, and I'm trying to output them all to a binary file and then read them back. I'm not convinced I have the syntax correct because when I am reading them back they are broken, i.e. don't seem to have any of the data they were given before they went into the file. The line before this I iterate through the data and output them all so I know they are ok before they are printed

This is the code that outputs the account into the binary file.

```
for (it = accounts.begin(); it != accounts.end(); it++)
{
    outFile.write((char*)&(*it).second, sizeof(Account));
}
```

Anyone know if this is ok?

EDIT: And it wasn't

```
for (it = accounts.begin(); it != accounts.end(); it++)
{
    outFile.write((char*)&(*(it->second)), sizeof(Account));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write memory addresses cast to `char*` to a file. These numbers will have no relevance whatsoever. Presumably you want to serialize the objects pointed at by those pointers. So first you need to find a means to serialize and de-serialize objects of that type, then write those to a file by re-referencing the pointers held in the map.

Comment: Yes I thought I was writing memory addresses which isn't what I want to do. Previously I had output an object like "out.write((char*)&anEmployee, sizeof(Employee));" but when pointer and map got involved it's extremely confusing

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you serialize objects for several reasons:

- if the object is polymorphic, most(all?) implementations will have a pointer to a virtual table inside the object, so you write that, but when you read it back, it is no longer valid.
- other pointers to members are written, but don't make sense when you read them back.

Serialization is not as easy as writing the bytes of the object to file.

The easy solution is to use an existing library - [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) come to mind.

Another is to implement it yourself, but that's hard, especially if you want support on multiple platforms/operating systems.

Comment: I should say, the program itself reads it back so it knows the definition of the class..it just doesn't seem to be writing anything. I've written a smaller program previously that did this successfully but I think I've gotten mixed up with pointer addresses etc and got lost as the other program wrote the object directly rather then mess with pointers.

Comment: @user1623990 as pointed out, having pointers in the class messes it up.

Comment: The class itself doesn't contain pointers, the map contains pointers to the object

Answer (score 0):

You will see adresses of memory and no more. You have to write much more complex method. See [Google protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) for some thoughts.